# How to create Microsoft Team via Microsoft Graph API with Owners specified by User Email rather than User ID?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, power-automate

**Desired Behaviour**

Create a Microsoft Team, with specified Owners and Members, in a Power Automate Flow using the HTTP connector to make requests to the Microsoft Graph API.

**Actual Behaviour**

This code shows how you can create a Microsoft Team whilst specifying it's Owners by `User ID`.

```
{
    "template@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    "displayName": "My Sample Team",
    "description": "My Sample Team’s Description",
    "members": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        "roles": [
            "owner"
        ],
        "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('0040b377-61d8-43db-94f5-81374122dc7e')"
    }]
}
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-application-permissions)

For reference, the Graph API docs entry for [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) (which is used to specify the `Owner` in the code above), specifies the endpoint syntax as:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Currently, I do not have access to users' `id` or `userPrincipalName`.

**What I've Tried**

I am using a Power Automate Flow with the SharePoint `For a selected item` trigger.

The list includes two columns of type `Person` where `Owners` and `Members` are specified.

In order to get a list of `Owners`, I am using the SharePoint connector's [Get item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#get-item) action on the selected item and then using an `Apply to each` control to iterate over each columns' values.

Below is the `Raw Output` of `Get Item` - the `Owners` column array is `TeamOwner_x002f_s`.

You can see that each object only has `DisplayName` and `Email` and not `User ID` or `userPrincipalName`:

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
        "Vary": "Origin,Accept-Encoding",
        "X-SharePointHealthScore": "1",
        "X-MS-SPConnector": "1",
        "X-SP-SERVERSTATE": "ReadOnly=0",
        "DATASERVICEVERSION": "3.0",
        "SPClientServiceRequestDuration": "68",
        "SPRequestGuid": "letters-and-numbers",
        "request-id": "letters-and-numbers",
        "MS-CV": "letters-and-numbers.0",
        "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000",
        "X-FRAME-OPTIONS": "SAMEORIGIN",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *.teams.microsoft.us local.teams.office.com *.powerapps.com *.yammer.com *.officeapps.live.com *.office.com *.stream.azure-test.net *.microsoftstream.com;",
        "MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices": "numbers-and-dots",
        "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
        "X-MS-InvokeApp": "1; RequireReadOnly",
        "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "false",
        "Cache-Control": "max-age=0, private",
        "Date": "Sun, 04 Jul 2021 06:42:53 GMT",
        "P3P": "CP=\"SOME CODES HERE\"",
        "X-AspNet-Version": "4.0.30319",
        "X-Powered-By": "ASP.NET",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Expires": "Sat, 19 Jun 2021 06:42:54 GMT",
        "Last-Modified": "Sun, 04 Jul 2021 06:42:54 GMT",
        "Content-Length": "3938"
    },
    "body": {
        "@odata.etag": "\"2\"",
        "ItemInternalId": "1",
        "ID": 1,
        "Title": "View",
        "Year": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "2023"
        },
        "Year#Id": 2,
        "ProgramType": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
            "Id": 0,
            "Value": "Program Type 01"
        },
        "ProgramType#Id": 0,
        "ProgramName": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "02"
        },
        "ProgramName#Id": 1,
        "TeamOwner_x002f_s": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
                "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "DisplayName": "User Name 1",
                "Email": "user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Picture": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Department": null,
                "JobTitle": null
            },
            {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
                "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_2@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "DisplayName": "User Name 2",
                "Email": "user_2@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Picture": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=user_2@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Department": null,
                "JobTitle": null
            }
        ],
        "TeamOwner_x002f_s@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser)",
        "TeamOwner_x002f_s#Claims": [
            "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "i:0#.f|membership|user_2@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
        ],
        "TeamOwner_x002f_s#Claims@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
        "Team_x0020_Member_x002f_s": [
            {
                "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
                "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_3@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "DisplayName": "User Name 3",
                "Email": "user_3@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Picture": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=user_3@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "Department": null,
                "JobTitle": null
            }
        ],
        "Team_x0020_Member_x002f_s@odata.type": "#Collection(Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser)",
        "Team_x0020_Member_x002f_s#Claims": [
            "i:0#.f|membership|user_3@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
        ],
        "Team_x0020_Member_x002f_s#Claims@odata.type": "#Collection(String)",
        "Status": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference",
            "Id": 0,
            "Value": "Details Added"
        },
        "Status#Id": 0,
        "Modified": "2021-07-04T03:57:16Z",
        "Created": "2021-07-04T03:51:18Z",
        "Author": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "DisplayName": "User Name 1",
            "Email": "user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "Picture": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "Department": null,
            "JobTitle": null
        },
        "Author#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        "Editor": {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser",
            "Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "DisplayName": "User Name 1",
            "Email": "user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "Picture": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/UserPhoto.aspx?Size=L&AccountName=user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "Department": null,
            "JobTitle": null
        },
        "Editor#Claims": "i:0#.f|membership|user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
        "{Identifier}": "Lists%252fMy%2bList%2bName%252f1_.000",
        "{IsFolder}": false,
        "{Thumbnail}": {
            "Large": null,
            "Medium": null,
            "Small": null
        },
        "{Link}": "https://my-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ExampleTeam/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=list-id-here&ID=1&ContentTypeID=content-type-id-here",
        "{Name}": "View",
        "{FilenameWithExtension}": "View",
        "{Path}": "Lists/My List Name/",
        "{FullPath}": "Lists/My List Name/1_.000",
        "{VersionNumber}": "2.0"
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to specify Team members by `Email` in the Graph API request?
Or do I need to somehow get the `User ID` of each user specified (and if so, what is the best way to do that)?

**Update**

I tried this `HTTP` connector `GET` request in the hopes it would return `User ID` for each `Person`:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/site-id-here/lists/list-id-here/items/item-id-here?expand=fields(select=TeamOwner%5Fx002f%5Fs)
```

But it returned even less information:

```
"fields": {
    "@odata.etag": "\"letters-and-numbers,2\"",
    "TeamOwner_x002f_s": [{
            "LookupId": 9,
            "LookupValue": "User Name 1",
            "Email": "user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
        },
        {
            "LookupId": 27,
            "LookupValue": "User Name 2",
            "Email": "user_2@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

[API docs reference for this approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

> Get specific column values of a listItem

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields(select=Column1,Column2)
```

Comment: At [Get a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request), i do see `userPrincipalName`, and `id` being returned. "So perhaps I could use the DisplayName returned from ....", No, use the `id`, or am i missing something?  (yes, experience with graph.. )

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user information from Microsoft Graph itself, what you can try out is [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with [filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter).

like this:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter(mail eq 'user_1@my-tenant.onmicrosoft.com')

OR

You can [list all users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and do a mail/displayName search(`Ctrl+F`) on results at [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

By these you will be able to get `userPrincipalName` as well as `id`.

**Permission required:-**
One of the following permissions is required to call this API.

- Delegated (work or school account) - User.ReadBasic.All,
  User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All,
  Directory.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All
- Delegated
  (personal Microsoft account) - Not supported.
- Application - User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All,
  Directory.ReadWrite.All

Thanks.